# <textarea> default content disappears when adding formControlName the <textarea> element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a Reactive Form in Angular 4.0.2, which has a `<textarea>` field with default content, pulled from the database. The content in the `<textarea>` is showing without any issues, but when I add the `formControlName="sectionContent"` to the `<textarea>` element, the content from it disappears.

`<textarea formControlName="sectionContent ">{{ section.sectionContent }}</textarea`>

This issue is only happening with the `<textarea>` element, as I have other `<input>` fields in the form, but those contents are still appearing.

The FormGroup looks like this:

```
this.sectionForm = new FormGroup({
  sectionTitle: new FormControl(),
  sectionContent : new FormControl()
});
```

Did anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using default value instead

```
this.sectionForm = new FormGroup({
  sectionTitle: new FormControl(),
  sectionContent : new FormControl(this.section.sectionContent)
});
```

template

```
<textarea formControlName="sectionContent"></textarea>
```

or using setValue/pathValue:

```
this.sectionForm = new FormGroup({
  sectionTitle: new FormControl(),
  sectionContent : new FormControl()
});
// after received data
this.sectionForm.patchValue({sectionContent: this.section.sectionContent});
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/NWgzGdUc9cDkKujPgrl4?p=preview

Document:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html

setValue:

> Sets the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object that matches the
>   structure of the group, with control names as keys.
>
> This method performs strict checks, so it will throw an error if you
>   try to set the value of a control that doesn't exist or if you exclude
>   the value of a control.

patchValue:

> Patches the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object with control
>   names as keys, and will do its best to match the values to the correct
>   controls in the group.
>
> It accepts both super-sets and sub-sets of the group without throwing
>   an error.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that: 
sectionContent : new FormControl(this.section.sectionContent)

but that throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sectionContent' of undefined" and It doesn't accept the 'elvis' operator (.?) either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TiepPhan I've tried that each approach, but none of them seems to work.

Comment: no way, please see this demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/NWgzGdUc9cDkKujPgrl4?p=preview

Comment: Yes, I've checked that, but it seems that your approach is different than mine, as you are not creating a new FormGroup as I do.

Comment: that things are same, this is sort syntax

Comment: By different, I meant that I use only one FormGroup and get the data from Services via RESTfull API

Comment: after it received data from api, just patchValue to update form

Comment: patchValue() actually worked, I had a problem with the type of the section which was 'ISection'. After I changed the type to 'any' it worked. Thanks again @Tiep