# how to use html tags inside reactive form control?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have something like this:

```
this.emailForm=new FormGroup({
      outcomeSubject: new FormControl('Hi<br />My name is John', Validators.required),
      outcomeNotes: new FormControl('<div>Hi</div><div>My name is John</div>', Validators.required)
    })
```

The element is textarea.
How to set tags inside textarea?
I have tried unsuccessfully with innerHTML however still see the html tags.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<textarea> default content disappears when adding formControlName the <textarea> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698965/textarea-default-content-disappears-when-adding-formcontrolname-the-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

For my case I found a simple solution like

```
const htmlStr = 'text1\ntext2\ntext3';
this.emailForm=new FormGroup({
      outcomeSubject: new FormControl(htmlStr, Validators.required),
      outcomeNotes: new FormControl(htmlStr, Validators.required)
    })
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have html. If you use actual HTML, it's stripped out.